# How to hide the mailpoet Field in cf7 form On my WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to register people to mailpoet through cf7, There is an add-on that does this but is it putes Automatically a Chuckbox
I want to hide the Chuckbox but everyone who completes the form will be Registered automatically.

This is the form

```
 <label> שם*
    [text* your-name] </label>
<label> שם משפחה*
    [text* famoly_name id:famoly_name] </label>

<label> אימייל*
    [email* your-email] </label>

<label> מספר ווצאפ*
    [tel* telfon-whatsapp] </label>

<label> עיר מגורים
    [text City] </label>

<label> שם האם*
    [text* mothers_name] </label>

<label> תאריך לידה
    [date Date_of_birth] </label>

<label> אני רוצה להרשם
   [mailpoetsignup* mailpoetsignup-564 id:123 mailpoet_list_3 default:on] </label>



[submit "הכנס אותי למבצע"]
```

this is the tag
[mailpoetsignup* mailpoetsignup-564 id:123 mailpoet_list_3 default:on]

and This is the link to the [site of the plugin](https://he.wordpress.org/plugins/mailpoet-contact-form-7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'hidden' attribute to hide a field:

[hidden mailpoetsignup* mailpoetsignup-564 id:123 mailpoet_list_3 default:on]]

Alternatively try hiding the field with css:

```
[mailpoetsignup* mailpoetsignup-564 id:123 mailpoet_list_3 default:on class:hideit]
```

Then add this to your theme's css file or add it via the WordPress customizer if it's available:

```
.hideit{
     visibility: hidden;
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: Then I'd suggest that that is an issue with mailpoet.

Comment: Here someone asked the same question (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/make-mailpoet-sign-up-a-hidden-field/) But He didn't answer, He said that i can use the css code, but I do not know code

Comment: @יהונתן3D I've updated my answer. Please upvote and accept the answer.